# Redundant or good practice - Structs

Tags: c

The question I have today is one of the questions about the balance of convenience and efficiency in programming, more specifically about the use of structs.

"A structure is a collection of one or more variables, possibly of different types, grouped together under a single name for convenient handling."

This excerpt is found in "The C Programming Language" together with the following basic examples:

```
struct point { 
   int x; 
   int y; 
};
```

and

```
struct rect { 
   struct point pt1; 
   struct point pt2; 
};
```

So far so good.

I began coding a program that calculates linear equations and this came out:

```
typedef struct point { double x; double y; } point;

typedef struct linearEquation { double mx; double b; } linearEquation;
```

point and linearEquation have the very same variables, two doubles.

So the question is:
Are these redundant and would one struct serve purpose for both or should I keep it for the sake of readability? Consider that functions need specific arguments and have specific return types.

I could for example substitute each one with something like:

```
typedef struct twoDs { double a; double b; } twoDs;
```

How would you handle this?

Comment: This seems opinion based. I'd argue that keeping separate `struct`s makes it harder to accidentally pass something as a wrong argument. Also what if you need to add a third double to `point` at a later time?

Comment: I think the question is a better fit for softwareengineering.stackexhange.com.

Comment: First, anyone who says saving a few characters is "efficiency in programming"?  Don't listen to a word they say.  A few characters or lines is trivial compared to actually making code readable and maintainable so that it works and works reliably.  If you hear, "This will save you from typing an extra line!", your response should be, "Go away.  Go far, far away. And don't come back."

Comment: A chair with four legs is not dog, just because it has four legs as well.

Comment: OT: Shouldn't `mx`  be just  called `m`?

Comment: Don't edit your question to remove the entire question.

Comment: Variables and types should have distinct names. Consider the declaration `point point` ... in this case the variable name (`point`) describes it's purpose, but things might get confusing. It's common practice to mark types using a suffix (note the `_t` in `stdint.h` , where you get `uint8_t`). See my answer for details.

Comment: @PaulHankin when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 3):

If you are ever writing any serious code, you should *always* keep separate types. It improves readability and maintainability, and the compiler is able to tell you about bad assigns.

The whole concept of typed languages is about this - after all, it's all just bytes in memory, so you could as well not use any types ever, and just adress the bytes directly. That might work, but would be the ultimate in unreadabilty and maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Aganju - type names are used for reading the code and maintaining it, so the fact that two different types are implemented in the same is irrelevant - they are still different.

Consider that in the future you might want to change the `linearEquation`.

For example, let's say future you decides to add cached results to the `linearEquation` implementation... would you add another field to `point`? would you start searching through the codebase for all references to `point` that are actually `linearEquation` in nature...?

Having separate types is much better for future you and it will make your job simpler and your life easier.

Another important point about naming is that type names should be distinct from variable names.

A common practice is to mark types using a suffix (note the `_t` in `stdint.h` , where you get `uint8_t`).

In many places `struct` types will have `_s` at the end, enums will have `_e` and pointer types are avoided as a rule.

This is quite misleading:

```
typedef struct point { double x; double y; } point
// ...
void func(void) {
   point point = {0,1}; // ... totally legit, right?!
   // many lines of code later...
   if(point.y) { // confusing, might be mistaken for a bug.
      // ...
   }
}
```

A better approach would be:

```
typedef struct point { double x; double y; } point_s
// ...
void func(void) {
   point_s point; // ... less confusing
}
```

Some people use the postfix `_t`, but I would avoid it since it's reserved.